# What is the maximum identifier length in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, naming-conventions, identifier, restriction

Whats the max number of characters that can be used for a VB.NET variable or procedure identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MSDN article [***Declared Element Names (Visual Basic)***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81ed9a62.aspx) the maximum length of an element's name (variable, method, class, etc.) is 1023 characters.

> An element name in Visual Basic must observe the following rules:
>
> - It must begin with an alphabetic character or an underscore (_).
> - It must only contain alphabetic characters, decimal digits, and underscores.
> - It must contain at least one alphabetic character or decimal digit if it begins with an underscore.
> - **It must not be more than 1023 characters long.**

This applies to fully qualified names as well. For example: `MyNamespace.SubNamespace.ClassName.MethodName`.

Comment: @Trevor - [Yikes indeed!](http://www.thedailywtf.com/articles/get_words_from_a_number_which_is_passed_as_a_perimeter_into_this_function)